# Simple arrows beside image Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a very trivial problem. I just needed two simple arrows (left and right) vertically aligned to the middle to the image. Arrows have to be responsive and become smaller with screen size.

My code now is just:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="offset-md-1 col-md-1">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" style="position:relative; top:50%"></i>
   </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 detail_pic">
        <img src="#image" style="width:80%;">
        <h2 style="text-align:center;">#Title</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" style="position:relative; top:50%"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This looks like the image below. But it doesn't work well when I size down the screen as the cols get stacked over each other. How do I get the arrows and the image in one col and make them responsive?

[image: On a desktop]

Comment: would you mind creating a JSBin or JSFiddle or Codepen with the assets and buttons included? That way we can just adjust the CSS because this is almost certainly a styling issue

Comment: Oh, no its not a styling issue, I'm using bootstrap so the div cols stack up on smaller screen sizes. I just needed a way to fit the arrows and image in the same col-md-8 such that the arrows are responsive and vertically middle aligned.

Comment: It is a styling issue. You need to write media queries and set the div's at the proper percentages for mobile (right now if they are stacked they are most likely at 100% each, you'll want 15%-70%-15% or something like that).

Comment: you can have automatically resizing arrow icons by using viewport units like this `img{ width: 2vmin}` which listens to the shorter of the width/height dimensions in your viewport, and uses a percentage of this dimension... css tricks link for more info https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/

Comment: But how do I actually place the left and right arrows beside an image in one div? Display inline is not working. The above code doesn't work well in small screen because it uses separate bootstrap grid col-md-1 for each arrow.   

Can u suggest how to to align the arrows with the image in the center in one div.

Comment: @AkinHwan It got solved. Thanks for the vmin idea, it makes life much easier

Comment: @VaishnavMK Glad that helped, let me know if the answer below solves your problem, if so mark it as the answer, if not I can edit it until it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the image size...you can have automatically resizing arrow icons by using viewport units like this `img{ width: 2vmin}` which listens to the shorter of the width/height dimensions in your viewport, and uses a percentage of this dimension... css tricks link for more info [css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units](http://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units)

For positioning the arrows in the center of the div use

```
img{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
```

a helpful article on flexbox vertical centering [phillipwalton.com](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/)